# Are hydroponic produce typically checked for bugs?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bugs, fruits, vegetables

I know that many soil-based fruits and veggies are checked for bugs. I assume that it may be primarily due to bugs that crawl on the ground or on the tree that causes this problem.

Is hydroponic produce also typically checked for bugs? Or, is there little or no concern regarding hydroponics as they are grown in the air, and usually in greenhouses. Maybe there is no concern of bugs crawling around, for some reason? (Flies and gnats, etc. can still enter the greenhouse.)

Comment: I heard that they are just naturally cleaner.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Visibly, they are! No dirt to deal with, and they usually taste better, too. If you can support that claim with a halachic tie in, that makes a good answer.

Comment: "I know that many soil-based fruits and veggies are checked for bugs.… Is hydroponic produce also typically checked for bugs?" In my experience, soil-grown produce is *not* typically checked for bugs. Only those labeled "is checked for bugs" are checked for bugs. I'd assume the same is true of hydroponic produce: that only those labeled "is checked for bugs" are checked for bugs.

Comment: @msh210 I am referring to kosher establishments, these days, not the general industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyroponically grown produce is not grown in the air, but in a medium such as rockwool with liquid either run through it, or that it sits in.  Typically, this is done indoors (e.g. in a greenhouse), however, there is exposure to the outside world.  There may be less opportunity for infestation, however,the possibility exists.  Insects can get in.  Unless there is specific certification as "bug free" produce, I would check for bugs.

[DANF editing citation:]

> In addition to romaine and other types of lettuce, one can grow herbs
>   such as cilantro, dill, and parsley.  Herbs are especially prone to
>   infestation, are difficult to check, and are not widely available to
>   the kosher consumer as ‘certified insect-free’.  The kit is helpful in
>   controlling infestation for these varieties.
>
> Hydroponically-grown vegetables (lettuce, herbs, etc.) sold
>   commercially without kosher certification should be thoroughly checked
>   since they grow under conditions unknown to the consumer.

The Star-K discusses the situation here: https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1121/hydroponics/

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for the great answer and the interesting Star-K article. I hope you discover pleasant questions, answers, and Torah insights, here. I'm editing in a summary line from that article, that I think is relevant.

Comment: "Hyroponically grown produce is not grown in the air, but in a medium such as rockwool": the rockwool surrounds the plant entirely? Don't plants need carbon dioxide (if I remember my high-school biology) and sunlight?

Comment: @msh210 I didn't know that you had the patent on the photosynthesis recipe. Can you share it? :-)